# How to apply an equalizer preset to an audio and create a new file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player

I have an audio file which doesn't sound good when played as-is, but when I use the “pop” equalizer preset in VLC, it sounds good. Hence I would like to create a new audio file with the equalizing effect “baked in”, so that it sounds good if someone else plays it as-is.

I found this question [How to use equalizer on ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/q/695843/) but it says to give the appropriate input to the ffmpeg equalizer filter. Then I did my homework and found [the “pop” preset settings that VLC uses](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/2dacb39432ad416f8a4adf4f7dfcbd900758019c/modules/audio_filter/equalizer_presets.h#L120). However due to insufficient technical knowledge I have no idea how to input this to the ffmpeg equalizer filter.

Further, this question [VLC: Apply an equalizer as part of the trascoding chain from the command line](https://superuser.com/q/1115785/) seems to indicate that VLC itself can do the task of creating the new file, but I may be mistaken again due to insufficient knowledge, and I'm not sure how to adapt it to my requirement.

My question: how can I apply the VLC presets linked above to my audio file and create a new one, whether with ffmpeg or VLC (or some other freely available tool that works on Linux)?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could use firequalizer ffmpeg filter to mimic magnitude response of VLC pop equalizer preset.

Comment: Hello. As I have said above, I am insufficiently technically knowledgeable to construct the correct filter command myself so would be very nice if you could show me how to adapt the VLC source to a VLC or ffmpeg command.